# Substitute multiple strings from a file over multiple files

Tags: awk, sed, string-substitution

Let's say I'm George Orwell and I want to replace all instances of "big" with "small", "rich" with "poor", "smart" with "stupid", etc across a bunch of files.  So I create a text file with one line per substitution:

file: substs.csv

```
big, small
rich, poor
smart, stupid
```

Now I want to apply those substitutions in `substs.csv` globally across a bunch of files.  I assume this would use a `sed` script.  Note that I'm happy to format substs.csv to have any format, as long as its one substitution pair per line.

What's the right tool, and what's the script that will do this?

Edit 1: It's fine to operate on just one file at a time.  I can do `foreach` or equivalent...

Edit 2: I can guarantee that substitutions on the right hand side don't appear on the left hand side, i.e., order of operation won't matter.

*[I'm tempted to just bust out python and do it there.  But this is a chance to refresh my unix tools chops...]*

Comment: `What's the right tool,` Well, define the term "right". How to judge if a tool is "right"? `hat's the script that will do this?` You can load your text file in `awk` and call `gsub` on each line on each pattern. You can parse your text file with `sed` to `s/big/small/g` format` and then call `sed` on it. Or you can use other tools, like mentioned python.

Comment: `Note that I'm happy to format substs.csv to have any format` --> in that case, use `s/big/small/g` per line and use `sed -f substs.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kamil said in the comments, there's probably a million different ways to stroke that cat ...

One that sprang into my warped mind was:

```
find -type f -name "*txt" -exec $(awk -F", *" 'BEGIN{printf "sed -i.bk "}{printf "-e s/%s/%s/g ", $1,$2}END{printf "\n"}' substs.csv) {} \;
```

Basically I'm building the sed-command on the fly (using your substs.csv and awk) and then use that via find to modify any files that end in `.txt`.  Your selection criteria may be wider, you may **not** want backups of the files (et rid of the `.bk` in  `"sed -i.bk "`) ... but it does what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's#(\S+), (\S+)#s/\\<\1\\>/\2/gp#' csvFile | sed -f - txtFile
```

Convert the csv file into a sed file and apply it to the text file.

N.B. The start/end word boundaries in the manufactured regexp.